# How do I return values in a loop to the main method?

Tags: java

I get the last value from my for loops returned, but I want all the values returned.  My output looks like this:

```
Celsius   Fahrenheit    |   Fahrenheit   Celsius   
40.0      87.80          |      120.00    -1.11 
39.0      87.80          |      110.00    -1.11 
38.0      87.80          |      100.00    -1.11 
37.0      87.80          |       90.00    -1.11 
36.0      87.80          |       80.00    -1.11 
35.0      87.80          |       70.00    -1.11 
34.0      87.80          |       60.00    -1.11 
33.0      87.80          |       50.00    -1.11 
32.0      87.80          |       40.00    -1.11 
31.0      87.80          |       30.00    -1.11
```

I need those other values to finish my output table.

```
public class TemperatureConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double celsius = 0;
        double fahrenheit = 0;
        int v = 0;
        double a = 0;
        double b = 0;
        double fahrenheitToCelsius = fahrenheitToCelsius(a);
        double celsiusToFahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(b);
        System.out.println("Celsius   Fahrenheit    |   Fahrenheit   Celsius   ");

        celsius = 40;
        fahrenheit = 120.0;

        while (celsius >= 31.0) {
            while (fahrenheit >= 30) {
                System.out.printf("%-9.1f%6.2f          |   %9.2f%9.2f \n", celsius, celsiusToFahrenheit, fahrenheit, fahrenheitToCelsius);
                celsius = celsius - 1;
                fahrenheit = fahrenheit - 10;
            }
        }
        celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);

        fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);

    }

    public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
        double fahrenheit = 0;

        for (celsius = 40.0; celsius >= 31.0; celsius--) {
            fahrenheit = ((9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32);

        }
        return fahrenheit;
    }

    public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
        double celsius = 0;

        for (fahrenheit = 120; fahrenheit >= 30; fahrenheit = fahrenheit - 10) {
            celsius = ((5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32));

        }
        return celsius;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Celsius   Fahrenheit    |   Fahrenheit   Celsius   
40.0      87.80          |      120.00    -1.11 
39.0      87.80          |      110.00    -1.11 
38.0      87.80          |      100.00    -1.11 
37.0      87.80          |       90.00    -1.11 
36.0      87.80          |       80.00    -1.11 
35.0      87.80          |       70.00    -1.11 
34.0      87.80          |       60.00    -1.11 
33.0      87.80          |       50.00    -1.11 
32.0      87.80          |       40.00    -1.11 
31.0      87.80          |       30.00    -1.11
```

Comment: This - `while (fahrenheit >= 30) {
                System.out.printf("%-9.1f%6.2f          |   %9.2f%9.2f \n", celsius, celsiusToFahrenheit, fahrenheit, fahrenheitToCelsius);
                celsius = celsius - 1;
                fahrenheit = fahrenheit - 10;
            }` move `celsius = celsius - 1;` outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code. Notice the nested method calls. You should not be looping inside your conversion methods.

```
public class TemperatureConverter {

  public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
    return 9.0 / 5 * celsius + 32;
  }

  public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
    return 5.0 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double celsius = 40;
    double fahrenheit = 120.0;
    System.out.println("Celsius   Fahrenheit\t|  Fahrenheit   Celsius   ");
    while (celsius > 30) {
      System.out.printf("%-10.1f%6.2f\t|%8.2f%12.2f\n", celsius, 
          celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius), fahrenheit, fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit));
      celsius--;
      fahrenheit -= 10;
    }
  }
}
```

prints:

`Celsius   Fahrenheit    |  Fahrenheit   Celsius
40.0      104.00        |  120.00       48.89
39.0      102.20        |  110.00       43.33
38.0      100.40        |  100.00       37.78
37.0       98.60        |   90.00       32.22
36.0       96.80        |   80.00       26.67
35.0       95.00        |   70.00       21.11
34.0       93.20        |   60.00       15.56
33.0       91.40        |   50.00       10.00
32.0       89.60        |   40.00        4.44
31.0       87.80        |   30.00       -1.11`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem, but I think you don't need the `for` loop inside the `celsiusToFahrenheit` and `fahrenheitToCelsius` methods, you're already passing the number.

Maybe if you change the method like this, it should work

```
public static double celsiusToFahrenheit (double celsius) {
  double fahrenheit = 0;
  fahrenheit = ((9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32);
  return fahrenheit;
}
```

And you have to move the call to this method inside the main loop!

Comment: Without a variable that is changing the return value will always stay constant.  In this case 57.60.  That is because the only variable, celsius is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Call the methods inside the while

System.out.printf("%-9.1f%6.2f          |   %9.2f%9.2f \n", celsius, celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius),   fahrenheit, fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit));

Comment: I believe that would cause me to call a method inside a method.

Comment: Yes you can do that and the inner most methods are processed first left to right.